# How to stay on the same angular page after refresh browser

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular2-routing, angular8

I'm developing angular app. Every time refresh the browser, the app move to home page. Any way to stay on the same page?

Update: here is the routes of the app.

```
export const secureRoutes: Routes = [
{path: '', component: DashboardComponent,  pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'user', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'table', component: TableComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'typography', component: TypographyComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'icons', component: IconsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'maps', component: MapsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'upgrade', component: UpgradeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'categories/new', component: AddEditCategoryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'categories/view/:id', component: ViewCategoryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'categories/edit/:id', component: AddEditCategoryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'categories', component: CategoriesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'categories/:category_id/view_product/:product_id',
        component: ViewProductComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'categories/:category_id/new_product', component: AddEditProductComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'categories/:category_id/edit_product/:product_id',
      component: AddEditProductComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'settings/edit', component: EditSettingsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'users/view_client/:id', component: ClientComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'orders', component: OrdersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], },
{ path: 'orders/:type/:id', component: OrderComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'adgroups', component: AdGroupsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'adgroups/new', component: AddEditAdGroupComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'adgroups/view/:id', component: ViewAdGroupComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
}
```

];

Here is also the AuthGuard used in the above routes.

```
    @Injectable()
    export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(
        private router: Router,
        public afAuth: AngularFireAuth
      ) {
      }
      canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(map((user) => {
          if (user) {
            return true;
          }
          this.router.navigate(['/login'])
          return false;
        }))
      }
    }
```

Comment: how do you serve your application?

Comment: Are you refreshing from page or component? In case you are refreshing from component then its just a modal and it will load the last page you were on, in your case home page.

Comment: what does your route config looks like?

Comment: I updated the post and included the routes of the app

Comment: what is your auth guard doing? is it rerouting to the another page on fail?

Comment: I've updated the post and included the AuthGuard. It's working fine. My notice is that when I refresh the page (or even after saving some code, and page is auto refreshed), the browser shows the same page for a second, then move to the home screen

Comment: you haven't still answered how you serve your app

Comment: I now serve app using ng serve (locally on my machine)

Comment: this behavior can bee seen when you get an error on the page upon initializing components that should be loaded. check the console for errors

Comment: I see no errors, and it happens with all components.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. The routes are OK, but I had a nav bar with language switch function. This language switch is being called to check the language and on some conditions it navigate to the home page.

Thanks for everyone.